# Mapbox error RMConfiguration setaccesstoken

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm getting this error running the sample:

```
"No visible @interface for 'RMConfiguration' declares the selector 'setAccessToken:'"
```

Any idea? The code what could be causing it? I'm using version 1.4.1 of the SDK

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[RMConfiguration configuration] setAccessToken:@"<access token>"];
    RMMapboxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"examples.map-zr0njcqy"];
    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [changelog](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/release/CHANGELOG.md), this was temporarily removed. Try the `develop` branch or else just use the `v3` API by supplying only a `mapID`.